# OpenCL random kernel behaviour when certain system size is exceeded

Tags: opencl

I am having a problem like this. Basically, I have a 2D grid allocated on host:

```
double* grid = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*(ny*nx) * 9);
```

Folllowing normal openCL procedure to put it on the openCL device:

```
cl_mem cl_grid = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double) * (ny*nx) * 9, grid, &error);
```

And Enqueue and launch:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, foo, 1, NULL, &global_ws, &local_ws, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

In the kernel function, simple arithmetic is performed on the 1st column of the grid:

```
__kernel void foo(__constant ocl_param* params, __global double* grid)
{
    const int ii = get_global_id(0);
    int jj;
    jj=0;

    if (ii < params->ny) {
        grid[getIndexUsingMacro(ii,jj)] += params->someNumber;
    }
}
```

And finally read back the buffer and check values.

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, cl_grid, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(double) * 9 * nx * ny, checkGrid, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

The problem is when the grid size (i.e. nx * ny * 9) exceeds 16384 * 9 * 8 bytes =  1152KB (* 8 since double precision is used).

- if using openCL on CPU, an error CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES is thrown when launching the kernel no matter what I set for global_ws and local_ws (I set them to 1 and the error is still thrown). The CPU is an Intel i5 2415m with 8GB of RAM and 3MB cache.
- If using openCL on the GPU (NVIDIA TESLA M2050), no error is thrown. However, when reading back the value from the buffer, the grid is not changed at all. It means it returns the grid whose values are exactly the same as before it is sent to the kernel function.

For e.g. When I set nx = 30, ny = 546, nx*ny = 16380, everything runs fine. The grid returned with the results changed as expected. But when ny = 547, nx* ny = 16410, the problem occurs both on CPU and GPU as described above. The problem is the same if I swap nx and ny, hence, if nx = 547, ny = 30, it still happens. Can you guys suggest what might be the problem here ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a synchronization issue.  `grid[index] += value` with the same `index` value may be executed concurrently by several work items.  This operation is not atomic, and all these work items will load `grid[index]`, add their value, and store it back, possibly losing some increments in the process.

To solve this, you can synchronize these work items using `barrier` if they are in a single work group, or enqueuing more kernels otherwise.

Another possibility is to ensure only one work item is able to modify a given element of the grid (usually the best solution).

If several work items need to work on a common subset of the grid, using local memory and local memory barriers may be useful.

Comment: You can't safely use barriers to do that, unless you manage to enqueue just one workgroup. A barrier in OpenCL provides synchronization for all workitems in a workgroup, but it does not synchronize inter-workgroup access.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant by: "if they are in a single work group".